# Backup SQL Server over Network share

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008, network-share

I have a SQL 08 Standard box that I would like to use a Maintenance Plan to backup a database over a network share? Is this possible as the GUI won't let me do that? It tells me it can't find the path. The SQL service has permissions to write on the share.

Comment: Can you access the path from Windows Explorer on the SQL Server?

Comment: when you say "SQL service has permissions to write on the share" is this a domain based account?

Comment: can you login local to the server as the service account then browser the remote share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually because the SQL server is running under an account that does not have permission to access the network shares.

If your SQL server account is not running under a "real" AD account, this might be the time to set that up. It's simple enough to do:

1. Create an account for your SQL Server to run under (Feel free to make the password long and complex, you only need it once).
2. Go to the Services control panel for that server
3. Right-click on the SQL Services (you should do the SQL Server and the Agent), go to Properties, Log On
4. Select "This Account" and enter the credentials for your SQL Server

   [image]
5. Restart the service

(May I suggest you test this first before shutting down a live SQL server)

Then you can specify share permissions on the network folder to state that the SQL Server account has full read/write access, but others might only have read access, or perhaps no access at all.

Comment: you'd think thats what he meant by "SQL service has permissions to write on the share" wouldn't you?

Comment: I was actually just in chat with Jacob and we went through the issue there, so it might not have been the case when I posted my answer

Comment: also I'd set the account to not expire.

Comment: Ohh yeah that too

Comment: Doubt this is a public facing sql server but if so then I hope they have proper control of the "domain user" group. Hackers are loving the fact that once they inject they pretty much know that the "domain user" group is poorly managed, as in its applied everywhere.